# About the dimension of a subspace of a vector space of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are vector subspaces of $V$ and $W$ respectively. It is known that

$$T = \{\alpha \in L(V, W) \mid α(x) \in Y \text{ for all } x \in X\}$$

is a vector subspace of $L(V, W)$. How to prove
that

$$\dim(T) = \dim(V ) \dim(W) − \dim(X)(\dim(W) − \dim(Y))\text{ ?}$$

I have no idea how should I start with.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I am new to here.

Comment: $L(V,W)$ is a vector space of linear transformations from $V$ to $W$.

Comment: Do you know what the dimension of $L(V,W)$ is? That might be a good place to start.

Comment: I know that $dim(L(V,W))$ is exactly $dim(V)dim(W)$. I guess this gives the first term on the right hand side, but I have no idea on the other terms.

Comment: Can you interpret the other term in the right hand side? For instance $\dim(W)-\dim(Y)$ is the same as the dimension of the orthogonal complement $Y^{\perp}$, and $\dim(X)\dim(A)$ will be the dimension of $L(X,A)$. Try to complete this line of argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can Write $V$ as a direct sum of $X$ and its orthogonal complement, i.e. 
$$ V=X\oplus X^{\perp}.$$
Now observe that 
$$T=L(X,Y)\oplus L(X^{\perp},W).$$
Using the fact that $\dim (L(U,Z))=(\dim (U))(\dim (Z))$, and  that $\dim (X^{\perp})=\dim (V)-\dim (X)$ you can easily conclude.

Comment: Nice answer. The OP should recognise that showing $T=L(X,Y)\oplus L(X^{\perp},W)$ is something that should be proved. It's a nice exercise.

Comment: Thanks. The whole idea is clear except that I still have no idea on how to show that
$$T=L(X,Y)\oplus L(X^{\perp},W).$$
I guess it is easy to write out the details for other parts so it remains for me to show this equality.

Comment: I give you a hint: First show that, if $V=X\oplus X^{\perp}$ then $L(V,W)\simeq L(X,W)\oplus L(X^{\perp},W)$. This can be done by consider a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ of $X$ and a basis $v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_{n}$ of $X^{\perp}$. Clearly $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$. Now observe (prove?) that every $\alpha \in L(V,W)$ is uniquely determined by the image of $v_i$ through $\alpha$. Then by definition of $T$ and by using the same argument as above you should be able to conclude.